# why Conditional VAE require conditioning of the encoder

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders

looking at [this blogpost](https://ijdykeman.github.io/ml/2016/12/21/cvae.html) and in many other, the cVAE looks like this:

[image]

Now, my question is... why do we need the label on the encoder level? Clearly that information is already inside the image, thus we should not need to tell the network this second part, I mean, to me it seems like

$$
l_{enc} \perp\!\!\!\!\perp y | x
$$

---

Update:
I've found [this paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper_files/paper/2015/file/8d55a249e6baa5c06772297520da2051-Paper.pdf) where they say that you actually train 3 components ($p(x|z,y)$, $p(z|x)$ and $q(z|x,y)$), and at the end of the day, they actually set $p(z|x) = q(z|x,y)$... so it seems that the encoder is actually not conditioned on the label

Comment: Regarding your update -- If you feel that you know the answer to your question, you can write it in the answer box below your question. But keep in mind that answers should be complete and detailed responses to the question.

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for the comment… the update shows that somebody do that, but for a different reason than the one that i’m asking for, so i think that it doesnt answers my original question